# bash for loop to exclude a particular sub directory

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a script that is performing a backup of directories using duplicity. We want to exclude some sub-directories from the 'for' loop. How do I achieve this?

Current script

```
backup_volume() { TARGET_URL=$1
   for vol in /dir/*; do
      VOLUME=$(basename $vol)
      duplicitiy backupcommand...
   done
}
```

There are some sub directories inside /dir/ that we want to exclude.. any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

`duplicity` knows to exclude directories

```
duplicity --exclude=/dir/somedir/someotherdir/dontbackup ...other options...
```

(this would be run to back up the whole of `/dir` in one go)

If you need to do a separate backup for each of the subdirectories of `/dir`, first of all, make sure that you match subdirectories by using the pattern `/dir/*/`, then test the filename of the directory against the ones that you want to avoid:

```
for vol in /dir/*/; do
    case $vol in
        */somedirectory/)    continue ;;
        */someotherdirtory/) continue ;;
    esac

    volume=$( basename "$vol" )

    duplicity ...
done
```

or,

```
for vol in /dir/*/; do
    volume=$( basename "$vol" )

    case $volume in
        somedirectory)    continue ;;
        someotherdirtory) continue ;;
    esac

    duplicity ...
done
```

or,

```
for vol in /dir/*/; do
    volume=$( basename "$vol" )

    case $volume in
        somedirectory|someotherdirectory|more here)    continue ;;
    esac

    duplicity ...
done
```

Or, with an extended globbing pattern in `bash`:

```
shopt -s extglob

for vol in /dir/!(somedirectory|someotherdirectory|...)/
    volume=$( basename "$vol" )
    duplicity ...
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Could these options work for a third / fourth level `subdir`? i.e. /dir/somedir/someotherdir/dontbackup but I want it to backup everything in: /dir/ /dir/somedir/ /dir/somedir/someotherdir (except dontbackup)